# How to have my Tableofcontent in english and pagenumbering in all pages?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

My page number only works for the first page and the table of contents is red and in portuguese, although I am using babel in english.

```
\documentclass[
article, 
12pt, 
oneside, 
a4paper, 
english, 
brazil]{abntex2}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
citecolor=black % cor da citação.
}
```

Comment: Change the order of `english` and `brazil` in the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `abntex2` is for "Typeset[ting] technical and scientific Brazilian documents based on ABNT rules", thus it internally loads `babel` with `brazilian`. If you do want use english language, add `\PassOptionsToPackage{main=english}{babel}` before the `documentclass`.

To change the color of links, use `linkcolor`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{main=english}{babel}

\documentclass[
article, 
12pt, 
oneside, 
a4paper, 
%english, 
%brazil
]{abntex2}

\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
%brazilian,
hyperpageref
]{backref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=black, % cor da citação.
  linkcolor=orange
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{title}
  \subsection{title}
  \section{title2}
  \subsection{title2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!